# Probability question without replacement

Tags: probability

C is the only part I am stuck with, which follows from parts a and b:

2. An urn contains five balls numbered 1 to 5. We conduct a sample of two balls with replacement.
   (a) Draw a diagram to represent the sample space for this experiment. Mark the following events on your diagram:
   A1 first ball drawn is a 5,
   A2 second ball drawn has a value less than 4,
   A3 sum of the values of the two draws is greater than or equal to 8.
   (b) Evaluate P(A1), P(A2), and P(A3).
   (c) Repeat parts (a) and (b) assuming no replacement

My answer is:

When 1 not replaced: P(A1)=1/5 P(A2)=2/5 P(A3)=3/10
When 2 not replaced: P(A1)=1/5 P(A2)=2/5 P(A3)=3/10
When 3 not replaced: P(A1)=1/5 P(A2)=2/5 P(A3)=1/4
When 4 not replaced: P(A1)=1/5 P(A2)=3/5 P(A3)=1/5
When 5 not replaced: P(A1)=1/5 P(A2)=3/5 P(A3)=3/20

ChatGpt tells me P(A1)=1/5 P(A2)=3/4 P(A3)=1/4 regardless of which ball is taken out and not replaced - I don’t think this is correct as the answer varies according to which ball is not replaced. Would I be correct in thinking so and is my answer above correct? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is hard to follow.  The header says "without replacement", the problem you quote says "with replacement", the first step in your calculation says "when $1$ is not replaced."  Which is it?  Are we replacing the first drawn ball or not?

Comment: Note:  ChatGPT is not very good at math...it's only good at sounding like it is doing math.

Comment: I’m stuck with part c of the question, as stated in opening sentence, which wants me to answer parts a) and b) but considering there is no replacement. Hope I make sense

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  It's not clear which part of the question you are analyzing....it's only part $c$?

Comment: Yes c is the only part I’m stuck on

Comment: So, edit your post to indicate that....it's not clear from you have written.  To your question:  If $A_2$ is just the probability that the second draw is $<4$, with no reference to the first draw, then $P(A_2)=\frac 35$, as each ball is equally likely to be drawn second.

Comment: To get $P(A_3)$ note that there are $\binom 52=10$ possible choices for the first two draws (ignoring order), and that $\{5,4\}$ and $\{5,3\}$ are the only two that sum to at least $8$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A1)=\frac{1}{5}$ with or without replacement

$P(A2)=\frac{2}{5}\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{4}=\frac{3}{5}$

We have two cases for A2 ball 1 greater than or equal to 4 which is the first term and we further have 3 balls of the remaining 4 less than 4 while if ball 1 is less than 4 we have 2 of 4 balls less than 4

To get sum 8 there is only 1 draw (disregarding order)
(3,5)
$P(A3)= \frac{2}{20}= \frac{1}{10}$

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the probabilities you've calculated are the ones the question asks for.  Some of what you've listed as the probabilities "when $\ i\ $ not replaced" seem to be the *conditional* probabilities of the various events *given* that the first ball drawn was $\ i\ .$ But the question asks for the *probabilities* of the events $\ A1,A2,A3\ ,$ not their *conditional probabilities* given the number on the first ball drawn.  And some of the probabilities in your list are definitely *not* those conditional probabilities.  If the first ball drawn is number $\ 1\ ,$ for instance, then the event $\ A3\ $ cannot possibly occur, so its conditional probability given that the first ball drawn was number $\ 1\ $ is $\ 0\ ,$ not the $\ \frac{3}{10}\ $ you've listed as the probability "when $\ 1\ $ not replaced".

The first thing part $(c)$ asks you to do is to repeat part $(a)$ for the case when the balls drawn are not replaced—that is, "draw a diagram to represent the sample space." Did you do that?  Though it might seem a little tedious, it can really help you see what's going on when you're learning the subject. I've included one possible representation below.  There are $20$ outcomes in the sample space, all of which are equally likely, so each has a probability of $\ \frac{1}{20}\ $ of occurring.  The outcomes in the event $\ A1\ $ are enclosed inside the blue line. Since it comprises $4$ outcomes it has a probability of $\ 4\times\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{5}\ .$ Likewise, the events $\ A2\ ,$ comprising the outcomes enclosed inside the red line, and $\ A3\ ,$ comprising the outcomes enclosed inside the green line, have probabilities $\ 12\times\frac{1}{20}=\frac{3}{5}\ $ and $\ 4\times\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{5}\ ,$ respectively.

[image]